# Capybara specs with time mocking headache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, capybara

I have been struggling with a very weird Capybara/Rspec behavior that has something to do with Time.now mocking.

First, I tried to define a set of specs with some models having three date fields set to the value on `DateTime.stub(:now) { DateTime.now.utc }`. When executed the whole test suite by doing `rspec spec` the test always failed, however, when doing `rspec spec/features/feature` all defined specs succedded.

While researching, some people suggested to use Timecop or Delorean gems to fake the current time to avoid having problems with Capybara. I tried both with no luck. I added to the `before/after each` blocks something like `Timecop.travel(time)`; all suite's specs succeeded this time, but executing the single spec file did yield failing specs .

What would be the best way to garantee deterministic outcomes from specs that deal with time as in *Compute my bicycle average speed during the last month/week/day* ?

I want to ALWAYS execute all such specs (defined in `rspec spec/features/feature`) within a given fixed date, let's say **June 13, 2010 15:70:00** so that I can do, `DateTime.now-1.year` and I get **June 13, 2009 15:70:00**, and the result is always consistent regardless if I am executing it as a separate spec file or as a suite.

Example of failing test:

```
describe "Stats Spec" do
  include IntegrationHelper

  before :each do
    I18n.locale = :en
    DateTime.stub(:now) { DateTime.new(2012,10,11,14,50).utc }
  end

  context "Given Loui has been cycling during the last year" do

    before(:each) do
      @loui = Fabricate(:standard_user, username: 'Loui')
      stub_track(:today, @loui.id, 3000)
      stub_track(:this_week, @loui.id, 5000)
      stub_track(:this_month, @loui.id, 8000)
      stub_track(:six_months_ago, @loui.id, 3000)
    end

    specify "he should be able to see his kms and today stats", js: true do
      # This spec checks that 3 km appear when clicked on "show today stats" button
    end

    specify "he should be able to see his kms and week stats", js: true do
      # This spec checks that 3+5 km appear when clicked on "show weekly stats" button
    end
  end
end

def stub_track(time, user_id, meters)
  # Fabricates a track using DateTime.now-(3.days/1.week/2.months) with the provided 
  # user_id and provided meters
end
```

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/timecop

Comment: could you post an example of a failing test?

Comment: I have added a brief fragment of code showing the kinds of scenarios I am trying to test.

Comment: If you use rails 4.1, maybe you could try with the travel_to test helpers